# Flutter: App Home Screen not loading properly [Resolved]

Tags: android, flutter, dart, debugging, mobile-application

I am developing a Flutter mobile app. I'm facing an issue with the Home Screen. The Home Screen is supposed to display a big text widget and two buttons, as well as a bottom bar consisting of containers with text or icons wrapped with gesture detection for onTap events.

Initially, the Home Screen loaded perfectly fine on the first run of the app. However, subsequent attempts to load the Home Screen have been unsuccessful, resulting in a distorted view, as shown in the attached image.

The source code for the app is available on my GitHub page

- [My Repo](https://github.com/PriyanshuMallick/Truth-or-Dare-game)
- [home_screen.dart file](https://github.com/PriyanshuMallick/Truth-or-Dare-game/blob/master/lib/screens/home_screen.dart).
- [Apk](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/67b14ab924aaee10c35e5ac992ed28f720230324032528/0a47f9)

I am not sure what could be causing this issue. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Image links:

[First image (expected Home Screen view):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pmLl.jpg)

[Second image (actual distorted view):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6nKa.jpg)

I have been reviewing the codebase of my app and tried to identify the cause of an issue, but so far, I have not found anything. When testing the app on the Android Emulator, it ran without any issues. However, when I tried to run the app on a physical device, it is not functioning as expected.

Specifically, I expected to find the problematic code segment and the issue to be fixed or at least identified. I would appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to resolve this issue. Thank you.

**Edit: Resolved Issue with HomeScreen Loading**

**Summary:**

The issue has been resolved. The problem was that the HomeScreen widget was being called prematurely before it had completely built itself. As a result, even after the initial load, when the HomeScreen widget was fully built and ready, it could not update itself or its state.

**Solution:**

I added a splash screen that provided enough time for the HomeScreen to load completely before being called. This resolved the issue and now the HomeScreen loads correctly with an updated state.

Comment: Check Debug Console if it shows any error, after restarting the app. If it throws some error or warning, please share it here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Prashant it didn't show any errors or warnings it works fine on an emulator but not on physical devices.

Comment: @bqubique the code is on GitHub. I provided the link to it on my post

Answer (score 0):

I was going through your repo in which I found you are loading your csv file in questions.dart

```
 final csvString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/___/Truth-or-Dare-Questions - Sheet1.csv');
```

this path seems to be wrong as your csv file name is questions, try this maybe it solves the problem

```
 final csvString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/questions.csv');
```

As you have not added any error from debug console that you are facing  I am not sure this thing is the main cause of your app not working. Hope this helps though.

Comment: That's not the issue I checked...  I just added ```___``` to my gitignore file. That's why it didn't show up on GitHub.